# How to install package offline with dependencies with Pip?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am quite new to python and i want to install a python package without internet. there are ample answers to this questions in stack overflow but i cant grasp it..

So i have downloaded the package in a machine with internet with

```
Sudo -H pip3 download intersight
```

It downloaded a tar file named intersight-1.0.9.5313.tar.gz and a bunch of .whl file
I have tared the whole directory and copied to the machine without the internet and untared it

Now how to install the package with its dependencies
I have tried `sudo -H pip3 install intersight-1.0.9.5313.tar.gz`
But came to know that it does not install the dependencies...

please help

Comment: pip only installs dependencies if it's connected to internet. when installing from file, it does not automatically resolve dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ intersight`